# How apply custom jQuery functions to selectors that match > 1 elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several textboxes that I want to apply a custom jquery function:

```
jQuery.fn.setReadOnly = function () {
    var o = $(this[0]);
    o.prop('readonly', true)
    .css('background-color', '#F0F0F0');
};
```

Now I need to do:

```
$('#txt1').setReadOnly();
$('#txt2').setReadOnly();
$('#txt3').setReadOnly();
$('#txt4').setReadOnly();
$('#txt5').setReadOnly();
```

I want to achieve the following:

```
$('#txt1, #txt2, #txt3, #txt4, #txt5').setReadOnly();
```

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try exactly that? (The last one.) You might be surprised.

Comment: Yes, and it didn't work.

Comment: It should. See David's answer.

Comment: Nearly : there is just the `this[0]` :) But you're right, this nearly works as it is...

Comment: I want to know the answer to this as well, so +1 for asking.

Comment: @Kiyura the OP's original code doesn't work because it explicitly breaks apart the supplied jQuery object and takes only the first element.  It would have worked if he had said `var o = this` (and also returned the result to ensure chaining worked).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your case you can just use `this` - it's already a jQuery object matching each of the supplied elements:

```
jQuery.fn.setReadOnly = function() {
    return this.prop('readonly', true).css('background-color', '#f0f0f0');
}
```

In the more general case where you want to do something explicitly on each DOM element other than call a jQuery function on the entire collection you would do this:

```
jQuery.fn.myFunc = function() {
     return this.each(function() {
         ...
     });
});
```

That's unnecessary in your particular case because the `.prop` and `.css` calls perform the `.each` implicitly.

Answer (score 1):

You're currently setting explicitly `$(this[0])`, which only accesses the first element.

You want to use `o = $(this);`

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8dY5R/)

Edit: as Alnitak points out, `this` will be a jQuery collection, and you could go right ahead to do `this.prop(...)` without the extra `$()` wrapping.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, the syntax for applying it to all matched elements is something like this:

```
jQuery.fn.setReadOnly = function () {
    return this.each(function () {
        $(this).prop("readonly", true).css("background-color", "F0F0F0");
    });
};
```

While it's not necessary to use the `.each` method on `this` to iterate through every matched item, it would be the correct way to use if you ever expanded this plugin to do more and needed to apply things to each element outside of jQuery methods (the `prop` and `css` parts).

Comment: the `.each` is unnecessary in this plugin because the `.prop` and `.css` calls do it implicitly.

Comment: @Alnitak Yes I understand that. But if this "plugin" was ever to be scaled, this format would probably be used. It's an example and one that doesn't add much overhead because of a simple `each` method. Anyways, I guess I should have mentioned that in the first place

Comment: you also have the overhead of calling `$(this)` inside the `.each` loop.

Comment: @Alnitak Overhead? Oh boy, watch out for the jQuery overhead. Go ahead and right a plugin that does more than this example without using `$(this)` anywhere

Answer (score 0):

See my upvote: use the this.each - it's better and returns for object chaining.

The 'this' object you're grabbing the first item out of - simply loop that with a:

```
for(var i = 0, len = this.length; i<len; i++){
    var o = $(this[i]);
    o.prop('readonly', true)
    .css('background-color', '#F0F0F0');
}
```

Untested, but i"m pretty sure that works.

Comment: Just a side note: "See my upvote" doesn't make much sense. Votes are anonymous.

Answer (score 0):

### This is how you'd write it

Don't forget to chain.

```
jQuery.fn.setReadOnly = function () {
    // return 'this' for chaining purposes
    return this.prop("readonly", true)
               .css("background-color", "#f0f0f0");
    });
};
```

Comment: @Alnitak: it is... But since `prop` and `css` already manipulate on **all elements in the set** we don't have to call `each`. You're correct about that. Let me correct my answer. I was too fast writing it apparently because I expected many answers quickly... :)