# How to make a jQuery plugin work on multiple elements at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I've made a combobox-plugin. To use it, you just have to call

```
$(elem).combobox(compensateElement);
```

EDIT:
Problem is that if you do

```
$('#1').combobox('form');
$('#2').combobox('form');
```

the plugin will break...

The elem is the select to be turned into a combobox, and the compensateElement is an element after which the plugin can insert a div that is the length of the suggestionsDiv-20px high. (I have a footer on my page that isn't pushed down by absolute positioned elements...)

Now, the problem is that this plugin can ONLY BE USED ON ONE ELEMENT! How can it be changed so it can work on multiple elements at once? It's more than a hundred lines of JS-code, so I do not expect the "converted" code!

I've thought of putting all element-specific variables into the this.data "object", but it didn't feel at all like a good solution. After running some RegEx find&replace on it and configuring it for a couple of hours, I didn't get it to work at all...

What techniques can I use?

Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: Didn't quite read the whole question, but how about? `$('#state, #another-id, .a-class').combobox('form');` ( Not sure if the `'form'` at the end is fine as it is. I don't know how that `'form'` is targeted ).

Comment: What do you mean with "work with multiple elements"? You want for example to do `$('select').combobox()` and apply this to all of them?

Comment: I mean to be able to turn multiple selects into comboboxes.

Comment: @Jonas Yes, that would be good, but the problem is that this plugin doesn't work anymore if you try to apply it to more than one element..

Comment: @SérgioMichels Yes, kind of. That would be great! But if it is applied to more than one element, the plugin doesn't work anymore. Just try with the code I provided you with.

Comment: @StudentofHogwarts by the way take a look at the [jquery boilerplate](http://jqueryboilerplate.com) and addy osmanis [jquery plugin patterns](https://github.com/addyosmani/jquery-plugin-patterns)

Comment: Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13567227/how-apply-custom-jquery-functions-to-selectors-that-match-1-elements

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that you have a [literal object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Object_literals), that will have his content replaced every time you call `m.init()`.

I suggest you to look at [this post](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/11/essential-jquery-plugin-patterns/), that explains good approaches to write JQuery plugins. If you see the "Lightweight Start", for example:

```
$.fn[pluginName] = function ( options ) {
        return this.each(function () {
            if (!$.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName)) {
                $.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName,
                new Plugin( this, options ));
            }
        });   
    }
```

this creates a new instance of the plugin object for each element, so you can maintain state consistently.

Comment: You, my friend, are a gullible one! Thank you very much! I feel so extremely stupid right now! I know what the problem was, but never that the solution could be that simple! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

you can call your plugin methods on each element with jQuery's each function. Remember inside your methods the keyword `this` will be pointing to current element not to jQuery object.

```
   $.fn.combobox = function(form) {
        var $this = this;

        return $this.each(function () {
             if (!m.initialized) {
                m.init.apply(this, [form]);
                $this.data('initialized', true);
             } else {
                m.updateList.apply(this);
             }
        });
    };
```

Comment: Hmm, this code makes it possible to do `$('select').combobox('form');` Right?

Comment: Yeah... it will iterate on every node and call the plugin method on that :)

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately that isn't my problem. Maybe I'll update the question. It is that if you do `$('#1').combobox('form');$('#2').combobox('form');`, the plugin will break.